# mongodump не работает

Tags: mongodb

Делаю mongodump, но, увы, не получается. Почему-то утилита просто подвисает и не отвечает. Делаю так:

```
mongodump --host 12.34.56.78 --port 27017
```

Как полечить?

При этом, если произвожу дамп с кластера `mongocloud`, то всё работает. В каком формате следует указывать параметры (видимо, хост). База не запаролена.

---

Получил вот такой ответ:

> 2019-08-20T15:29:42.810+0300  Failed: can't create session: could not
>   connect to server: server selection error: server selection timeout
>   current topology: Type: Single Servers: Addr: 12.34.56.78:27071, Type:
>   Unknown, State: Connected, Average RTT: 0, Last error: connection() :
>   dial tcp 12.34.56.78:27071: connect: connection refused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mongodump --uri "mongodb://10.80.43.26:27017/market-radar"
```

Следует указывать `uri` и брать в кавычки. Перед тем как начнётся дамп, будет большая задержка. Её нужно выждать.